# After AndroidStudio update,Gradle file not getting downloaded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I am working on Android Studio 1.5.1. Using this version of Studio, I can create new projects, there are no issues for creating new projects. But when I try to import other projects (existing in my Studio sample projects or Git Projects) into my work space, the gradle try to download the files, but it takes a long time and, unfortunately, I still can't open any single  existing project in my Studio 1.5.1:

[image]

Comment: What is your Android Studio error log/event log?

Comment: You have to change the Gradle versions of old project to new one.

Comment: 1.Try to use graldew assemble -info in terminal to get more info.2.And can you try to import a project with less depends?3.Go to the build.gradle in old project and change gradle version to new project's  gradle version.5.Try to upgrade to android studio 2.0,it's faster.

Comment: Still i didint get any updation for studio 2.0

Comment: Hey i dowloaded the studio 2.0 and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem after gradually upgrading from Android Studio 1.3 to 1.4 & now to 1.5.

I fixed the problem by performing a clean install of the latest Android Studio after completely uninstalling the existing version.

Further, I also downlaoded API 22 & 21 in addition to most current API 23.

Building the gradle still takes upto 20 minutes for certain older projects of Eclipse, but it's at least opening now.